# Dynamically Run Notebook using another python script

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have many Python notebooks I want to run dynamically while showing the output to the current terminal and also saving the output for each cell in the notebook as well.
I want the live outputs from the notebook, i.e change the stdout to the current terminal, as each notebook has long processes and prints a loading bar, to show the current progress.

Is this possible, and if yes then how?